# Getting information from the battery usage indicator

Tags: android

What I would like to do is get the data from the built in battery usage indicator screen in Android. This is the screen that displays what has been using battery life in percentages, such as display, cell standby, wifi etc.

I've searched through the Android developer site and can't seem to find any information on this. I assume this data isn't accessible through an API. Has anyone been successful in getting this data?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is handled by the class `android.os.BatteryManager`. You have to register BroadcastReceiver for receiving of the intent `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` and you get info. Intent extras `EXTRA_SCALE` and `EXTRA_LEVEL` will help you to obtain the information you need.